# Hierarchical reusable control in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, structure

I'm learning angularjs and I'm a bit troubled regarding the re-usability of custom controls. I have a custom control which I want to re-use in the following scenarios:

**Scenario 1**: The custom control has a controller with scope variables that I want to use in another controller. In this case my custom control controller would be the child controller and I would access my parent's controller scope values by using:

```
$scope.$parent.property = value;
```

**Scenario 2**: The custom control needs to be rendered separately on the page and is now the parent controller. In here I would access the scope using the default $scope syntax:

```
$scope.property = value;
```

I want to re-use the control/controller in these 2 scenarios. The custom control needs to be able to access the $scope and I'm currently rendering the custom control using ng-include as shown below. I would like to render this control in another controller or separately on a page.

What would be the best way to handle both scenario's?

Comment: What you are describing is a use case for directives. It is also very rare that you ever need to use `$parent` when your components are structured well. A directive can be used throughout the app and  you would pass in data needed either through the attributes or through a service

Comment: Some code samples and demo would help if you want more defintive answers

Comment: I will have a closer look at directives again and create an example if needed. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this issue using directives, I passed the scope variables to my directive using the appropriate bindings.